# Why do I not have a Tahr wallpaper

Tags: upgrade, desktop-background, 14.04

I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 yesterday, and was surprised that the new included wallpapers do not contain any with a Tahr in them.

I had come to think of the cartoonish animal background as a fun indicator of the Ubuntu version being run. Does this not exist for 14.04?

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen a release without the drawn animal.  I'm a fan of the previous Salamander wallpaper.

Answer (score 2):

This time around (for a first time in several releases) Canonical did not include a cartoon version of an animal, I was also suprised of that yes! But no worries, that doesn't mean the community didn't make any!

Personally, I liked this one: https://www.flickr.com/photos/pintame/12942455895/in/pool-2535978@N21